# Desativar botão após redirecionamento

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tenho a seguinte situação: Uma tela (Tela1) onde o usuário escolhe o botão referente a um Conjunto(uma entidade do meu programa), ele clica e abre um form de cadastro para aquele Conjunto.

Ao clicar em cadastrar, os dados do form são salvos no banco e o usuário é redirecionado para Tela1 novamente para poder cadastrar os próximos.

Alguém saberia como eu conseguiria gerar essa Tela1 com o botão referente ao Conjunto preenchido anteriormente desativado? Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, acredito que para este caso, voce deveria armazenar o resultado da operacao do banco de dados, algo como isto:

```
if($var->save()){
$auxiliar = true;
}
```

Antes de enviar para o proximo formulario, voce redireciona retornando a variavel auxiliar, se for como TRUE, voce só precisa desativar o botao com alguma linguagem (Node, Javascript e etc), verificando seu estado(True ou false).

ex:

```
return redirect()->with($auxiliar);
```